# Read 1D and 2D Barcode from USB Barcode Scanner using C#.Net in WinForm Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new with barcode techniques. i want to build a windows form application to manage the item inventory by reading data from barcode.

please suggest me the right USB Barcode scanner Device(which one will easy to integrate with .Net) and C#.Net SDK or Active X Control to complete this application.

Thanks.

Comment: Just use [google](https://www.google.it/search?q=barcode+reader&oq=barcode+reader&aqs=chrome..69i57.2332j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=barcode+reader+c%23) and you' ll receive thousand of results

Comment: USB scanner is a keyboard...

Answer (score 1):

Most of USB barcode sacaners act exacly like keyboard. You get input in numbers. No need for extra coding yust put focus at texbox control an subscribe to ENTER event. Most of barcode scaners also can be programed to have prefix special character. So you can in your app listen keybord unput for that special character and than focus to texbox so string from barcode is always going to be writen in texbox contol mentoed for barcode inputs

Comment: Can you give met the links for sample code to read data from barcode scanner. it will help me a lot.

Comment: @Vinod No need for any code. If you connect USB Barcode scanner to host it will act as keyboard. Open notepad and do scan, you will get barcode in digits. There is nothing specail with barcodes. you can simulate barcede by typing digits on your keyboard.  It is just HID (human interface device). It can work whit any program Word, Excel NotePad and also with your winform app

Comment: Thanks a ton for you kind reply.

Can you suggest me USB Scanner Model and Company Name which is capable to read data from both 1D and 2D Barcodes and also work perfect with .Net Application. And it's easily available in Indian Market.